# how to assign and remove values of ng-model using checkbox?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="{{item}}" data-ng-model="untilcancelled" ng-init="untilcancelled=true"/>Until Cancelled</label>
<input type="text" ng-if="!untilcancelled" sipenddate data-ng-model="item.SIPTo" readonly/>
```

I have a checkbox which on checked I have to assign default value to `item.SIPTo`. Otherwise if unchecked I want to enable entering different to `item.SIPTo`
.The given textbox is a `Datepicker`

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-change on check box, check the value of 'untilcancelled'. Then update your 'item.SIPTo'

```
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-change="updateItem()" value="{{item}}" data-ng-model="untilcancelled" ng-init="untilcancelled=true"/>Until Cancelled</label>
```

```
//controller function
$scope.updateItem = function() {
    if($scope.untilcancelled) {
    // check here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to toggle (true/false only)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.MyScopeModel = {
    Selected: true,

  };


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.2/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkToggleId" name="chkToggleName" ng-model="MyScopeModel.Selected" />

  <label ng-if="MyScopeModel.Selected" for="chkToggleId">
    I am selected
  </label>
  <label ng-if="!MyScopeModel.Selected" for="chkToggleId">
    I am not selected
  </label>

  <br>
  <br>Check box value : {{MyScopeModel.Selected}}


  



</div>
```